# Filesystem watch in Rust

Tags: rust, filesystemwatcher

I'm trying to implement a filesystem watcher in Rust. I can receive events when filesystem objects have changed but determining what change was made has me stumped. I found code on the latest released version of the Notify package [here](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.15/notify/) that takes me almost the whole way there.

How can I extract the path and type out of the `event`? The event is an enumerated type, yet somehow when it's printed, I see all the info I want.

I am obviously missing something very fundamental.

```rust
use notify::{watcher, RecursiveMode, Watcher};
use std::sync::mpsc::channel;
use std::time::Duration;

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = channel();
    let mut watcher = watcher(tx, Duration::from_secs(10)).unwrap();
    watcher
        .watch("/tmp/path", RecursiveMode::Recursive)
        .unwrap();

    loop {
        match rx.recv() {
            Ok(event) => {
                // **>> event.filename? event.type? how?
                println!("{:?}", event);
            }
            Err(e) => println!("watch error: {:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you need to then `match` on the `event`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a debounced watcher, the event you get is of type [DebouncedEvent](https://docs.rs/notify/4.0.15/notify/enum.DebouncedEvent.html). The enum variant specifies the type, and its contents is the path(s). To get it out of the event, you should match on the event for the desired event types:

```
match &event {
    Read(path) => {
        // do thing
    }
    Rename(src, dest) => {
        // do other thing
    }
    _ => () // don't care about other types
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Rust really has me scratching my head a lot, but then once I see how to do it, it makes sense.